# structure with byte fields collate to byte[]

Tags: c#, struct, arrays

Hi i have a structure as follows

```
    private struct MessageFormat
    {
        public byte[] Header; //start of message
        public byte Fragmentation; //single packet or not
        public byte Encryption; //encrypted message
        public byte[] Authentication; //password
        public byte[] Flag; //to locate end of auth
        public byte[] Data; //info
        public byte[] Trailer; //end of message
    }
```

is there a handy way to convert the whole MessageFormat into a single byte array[] after i populate all the fields?

Comment: Try looking up the BitArray class.

Comment: There is a handy way, but you probably won't like it.  The .NET framework way frets a lot about making sure that the byte[] can be safely converted back to the original object.  The not-so-handy way is BinaryWriter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written a sample code which will do exactly what you asked. It combines Reflection and `Buffer.BlockCopy` but it can be made MUCH more performant (i.e. boxing `format` in advance, avoiding anonymous types -- and their awkward, redundant initialization in the example -- or even not using Reflection at all and hardcoding the serialization method). Note that the method I offer doesn't use a buffer for the result but calculates the final length before allocating the array.

```
var format = new MessageFormat
{
    //Initialize your format
};
//Gets every instance public field in the type
//Expects it to be either byte, either byte[]
//Extracts value, length and type
var fields = typeof (MessageFormat).GetFields().
    Select(f => f.GetValue(format)).
    Select(v => new
    {
        Value = v,
        Type = v is byte ? typeof (byte) : typeof (byte[]),
        Length = v is byte ? 1 : (v as byte[]).Length
    }).
    ToArray();
//Calculates the resulting array's length
var totalLength = fields.Sum(v => v.Length);
var bytes = new byte[totalLength];
var writingIndex = 0;
foreach (var field in fields)
{
    //If the field is a byte, write at current index,
    //then increment the index
    if (field.Type == typeof (byte))
        bytes[writingIndex++] = (byte) field.Value;
    else
    {
        //Otherwise, use a performant memory copy method
        var source = field.Value as byte[];
        var sourceLength = source.Length;
        Buffer.BlockCopy(source, 0, bytes, writingIndex, sourceLength);
        writingIndex += sourceLength;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each byte array is actually storing a reference to the byte array, so it's not directly a single array.

You'll need to build a single array out of this data.  I would, personally, make method to do this, create the resulting `byte[]` of the appropriate length, and then use [Array.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft.aspx) to copy into the result array.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do it, but all of them require pulling of the bytes field by field.

Here's one:

```
var msg = new MessageFormat();
var arr = new byte[msg.Header.Length + 1 + 1 + msg.Authentication.Length + msg.Flag.Length + msg.Data.Length + msg.Trailer.Length];
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(arr, 0, arr.Length, true))
{
    stream.Write(msg.Header, 0, msg.Header.Length);
    stream.WriteByte(msg.Fragmentation);
    stream.WriteByte(msg.Encryption);
    stream.Write(msg.Authentication, 0, msg.Authentication.Length);
    stream.Write(msg.Flag, 0, msg.Flag.Length);
    stream.Write(msg.Data, 0, msg.Data.Length);
    stream.Write(msg.Trailer, 0, msg.Trailer.Length);
}
```

You could also use `Buffer.BlockCopy` or `Array.Copy`.